# Scanner to assess hardening of IT System (Network and compute servers)

Tags: hardening

Does Symantec Compliance Control Suite helps scanning the servers (windows, Unix), network routers and switches for system hardening of the devices?

I believe the typical *vulnerability* scanners (example McAfee Vulnerability Manager) are only good for identifying the missing patches, unsecured ports.

This is not specific to any audit or regulatory requirement, but in general to ensure that all systems are hardened to industry the best practices.

Comment: Did you ask Symantec?

Comment: That is a question to ask on their support page